# what is the best way to input a whole date interval to api.ai dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

i'm working in dialogflow in spanish language and i am having troubles with how dialogflow recognizes the dates intervals, my intention is to get a whole date for an event including starting hour and finishing hour, but when i use date-period, time-period, date-time, etc. They just recognize a little part of the input and i can't obtain something like this:
{"startDate":"2018-04-01T10:00:00-05:00","endDate":"2018-04-01T11:30:00-05:00"}

my input used to be like this "create a reunion starting june 5th at 2:00 until june 5th at 3:00" (in spanish, obviusly there are big differences but this is an aproximation, also sorry for my english).

can anybody give me some advice on how can i improve the dialogflow recognition of whole date intervals?

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot of my agent intent for reading the dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr4Ke.png)

this is the best way i found so far to handle dates. On the fulfillment side i added logic read in all the values if it exists.
and then remove the date in the time, and time in the date as you see crossed out on the bottom right of the image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)